# LimeJS animation.Sequence does not complete

Tags: loops, animation, sequence, limejs

i have got a probling concerning my animation.Sqeuence.
Only the first Sequence Element is being executed. The 2nd is ignored.
I want the Sprite spell_1 to move to the Hero (hero_x_exact,hero_y_exact), and after that to the destination.
Each element works fine for itself but not in a Sequence.

```
goog.require('lime.animation.Sequence');

...

var spellmovement = new lime.animation.Sequence(
    spell_1.runAction(new lime.animation.MoveTo(hero_x_exact,hero_y_exact).setDuration(1).enableOptimizations()),
    spell_1.runAction(new lime.animation.MoveTo(target_coord_x_spell,target_coord_y_spell).setDuration(1).enableOptimizations())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What might work better is using a spritesheet with each animation on the spritesheet Then you can build something that loads each animation by name. Obj_Walk001.png, Obj_Walk002.png

Then create a method to read each animation per frame in the scheduling manager.

You can find an example of this code in limejs/lime/demos/test. Then goto run.htm and click on Frame4 this one will show you how limejs is going it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but i dont know how this could help me. The Problem is, that after moving the sprite, oder after seting a new position to a sprite, i cant move it. The Layer turns grey...